# SVN+SSH and Sourceforge

Tags: windows, svn, sourceforge

I'm new to both Sourceforge and SVN (SilkSVN on Windows).

I managed to check out a project using

```
svn co --username=zeroth123 svn://zeroth123@svn.code.sf.net/p/stddecimal/code/trunk stddecimal-code
```

However, every time I try and use ssh (so I can check in for example) it fails with

```
> svn co --username=zeroth123 svn+ssh://zeroth123@svn.code.sf.net/p/stddecimal/code/trunk stddecimal-code
svn: E720087: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://zeroth123@svn.code.sf.net/p/stddecimal/code/trunk'
svn: E720087: Can't create tunnel: The parameter is incorrect.
```

I've set `SVN_SSH` to point to my fully qualified `plink.exe` and it makes no difference. I also tried changing it to `junk.exe` and didn't get anything different, so I don't think we're even looking at `SVN_SSH`, which exhausts all of the advice I've been able to find on the Sourceforge and other forums.

For the record I am the project administrator and therefore have write permissions (or at least think I do!)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please make sure to post the solution if you find it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`%SVN_SSH% needs to be set *correctly* and an SSH key needs to be registered with Sourceforge.

Note that new Sourceforge projects are *version 2.0* by default, while 99% of the Sourceforge documentation is for version 1.0 and appears outdated.

These instructions assume you have `SVN` and the `PuTTY` tools installed, and that you can successfully access your project using a non-secure protocol, eg the read-only `svn checkout svn://USER@svn.code.sf.net/p/PROJECT/code/trunk PROJECT-code` style command should work.

These instructions explain how to do the same with `svn checkout svn+ssh://...` which is needed for write access to Sourceforge.

1. Set `%SVN_SSH%` to the fully qualified path of your SSH client. E.g. `setx SVN_SSH "C:/Program Files (x86)/PuTTY/plink.exe"`

   - `svn` expects **forward slashes or double back-slashes** in the path
   - You may have to reopen a `cmd` window
   - Test by typing `%SVN_SSH%` at the prompt and confirm you get your ssh programs help screen (or whatever behaviour you expect from executing with no arguments)
2. (Optional?) Cache the server RSA key. Open `PuTTY`, login to `svn.code.sf.net` (or whatever the server of your project is). A prompt will appear asking if you if you want to cache the server RSA key - click Yes.

   - You might not need to do this, if not when you use SVN to connect ot your project for the first time you will be asked the same question. Type `y`.
   - However, I did this because I thought the interactive prompt could be part of the problem.
3. Create a public / private key and register the public key with Sourceforge.

   - On creating a key, more info [here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter8.html)for example.
   - If you use `PuTTY`, use `PuTTYgen` to create the key, and make sure the private key is loaded in `pageant`. Ironically [Launchpad](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/CreatingAnSSHKeyPair) has excellent instructions.
   - The public key can be registered on Sourceforge by navigating to `Home > Account > Services` and clicking `Edit SSH Keys for Shell/CVS`.
4. Now a checkout using `svn+ssh` protocol should work!

Comment: Please note that the name of the variable is %SVN_SSH% (and not %SSH_SVN%, as indicated in 1.)

Comment: A couple things: one, I tried lots of things before coming to this site, so it looks like it's important that `appdata/subversion/config` doesn't have anything under the ssh tunnel. Also, I don't know what `paegent` is, but `pageant` worked for me! (after many many minutes of bashing my head against the wall trying to figure out why this doesn't work.)

Answer (score 9):

I followed the instructions [here](http://ohadsc.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/working-with-the-new-sourceforge-svnssh-protocol-in-windows/) and it worked. Its a quicker method that doesn't require uploading keys etc.

1. Download `plink.exe` from http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/plink.exe
2. Place the `plink.exe` in your windows installation directory (`%windir%`)
3. Open the following file using Notepad `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config`
4. Add or Replace the following line in the `[tunnels]` section (replace login and pwd with your sourceforge login and password)

   ```
   ssh = c:\\windows\\plink.exe -batch -l <LOGIN> -pw <PWD>
   ```

   (note the double backslash)
5. Save and close the file

Comment: Or use forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that Tortoise was initially installed on the D drive. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it on C without changing the related settings. The solution was to copy the TortoiseSVN folder from C drive to its original location in D drive.

Answer (score -1):

For anybody (like me) working with Tortoise SVN who has it working for Tortoise SVN but needs command line access for easier bulk analysis... and doesn't want to go through the faff of registering an SSH key.

1. Copy the value you are using in Tortoise - Settings - Network - SSH Client (mine has username, password arguments)
2. Edit the command line configs ssh line in %APPDATA%\Subversion\config as per the answer above to use the line you copied from Tortoise

That way, you can use the Tortoise Plink.exe with arguments for username and password.